# Bootstrap 4 Remove the first forward slash in breadcrumbs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

On my breadcrumbs in Bootstrap 4 after the first li I need to be able to remove forward slash

Change

Location: / Catalog

To

Location: Catalog

> Question: How am I able to remove the first forward slash on bootstrap breadcrumbs

[image]

I tried

```
.breadcrumb-item:first-of-type::before {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    color: #868e96;
    content: "";
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li class="breadcrumb-item">Location: </li>
<?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: The item you want to remove this from is _not_ the first one ... _because_ you inserted your `Location:` as the first actual breadcrumb item. This would be easier if you either removed the `breadcrumb-item` class from that first item (and add some additional styling, like floating it to the left and some margin, yourself); or - not make this an actual item in the first place, but add `Location: ` as a pseudo element on the ordered list itself ...

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped and contributed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is this.

Since Bootstrap adds the `/` before the elements starting on the second element, we have to select the second element by using the `nth-child()` CSS selector like so.

```css
.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">Location: </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Content</a></li>
  </ol>
</div> 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use selector `.breadcrumb-item:first-of-type+.breadcrumb-item::before` to set `content` of `:before` pseudo-element as you wish:

```css
.my-breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item:first-of-type+.breadcrumb-item::before {
    content: "";
}

.dot-breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item:first-of-type+.breadcrumb-item::before {
    content: "...";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Data</li>
</ol>

<ol class="breadcrumb my-breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Data</li>
</ol>

<ol class="breadcrumb dot-breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Data</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: _“Use selector `.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item::before`”_ - that changes the divider between _all_ items ... (`.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item` matches _all_ .breadcrumb-item but the first one, because every other one of those does have an element with the same class as previous sibling.)

Comment: It removed both of the forward slashes

Comment: @CBroe Didn't notice you wanted just first divider removed. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The before selectors begin on the 2nd child. So you could so this:

```css
.breadcrumb-item:nth-child(2):before  {
  content: '';
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

I also overrode Bootstrap's `padding-right` to account for the new spacing between the list-items.

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector,

```
.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item::before{
    content: ">";
    color: white;
 }
```